# Rails 4 - method to check matching attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, devise

I am trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I am using devise and want to write an after sign up redirect path based on the following logic.

I have a user model that includes an :email attribute. I have an organisation model that includes an :email_format attribute (email attribute holds the part of the email address that comes after '@'. I have a profile model (which contains the user's information that can be altered by the user itself).

The associations are:

User - has_one: profile
Profile - belongs_to :user, belongs_to: organisation
Organisation - has_many :profiles

If the user (registering) inputs an email address that includes an email format that is saved in the db, then I want to associate that new user's profile with the organisation that has the matching email format.

Example:

New user's :email = bob@cat.com

I then check the organisation table to see if any :email_attributes stored are 'cat.com'.

If they are, then the user profile for the new user, is associated with the organisation that has the matching email_format (so the organisation_id in the relevant profile table is set to match that organisation id).

Here's my best attempt at writing this:

registrations controller:

```
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    # check if the email address the user used to register includes the email format of an organisation
    if  @user.email.includes? @organisation(:email_format) 

    # if it does match, then update the user profile so that the org id equals the org id for the org that has the matching email format     

      @user.profile.organisation_id.update_attribute(organisation.id == (@organisation.email includes? :email_format)) 
    else
      # set up a mandrill email sender to send this message
      set_flash_message('We are just getting started and will get in touch with 
        you as soon as we have onboarded your organisation')

    end
  end
```

I'm new to this and don't understand how to query things well. Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

NEXT ATTEMPT

Taking the suggestion below, I've tried to add an after_create callback to my profile model as follows:

```
after_create :update_organisation

  def update_organisation
    Profile.update_attribute(organisation_id: :matching_org_id) # Associations must be defined correctly for this syntax, avoids using ID's directly.
    # Profile.save
  end


  def matching_org_id
    if @self.user.email.includes? @organisation(:email_format) 
# how do you ask for the organisation with the matching email format id

        profile.organisation_id: organisation.id
    else
      TBC
    end
  end
```

This isn't working. I'm not sure how to express this method correctly. I'm currently getting an error that says:

```
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n' if @self.user.email.includes? @organisation(:email_format)
```

Answer (score 0):

**First problem:**

This part is fairly dangerous: you could have `bobcat.com@gmail.com` return a false positive.

```
if  @user.email.includes? @organisation(:email_format)
```

Perhaps you can use store a regex format and check it via

```
/@cat.com$/ =~ @user.email
```

Try out the formats at [rubular.com](http://rubular.com/)

**Second problem:**

The update method should be something similar to this.

```
@user.profile.update(organisation_id: @matching_organisation.id)
```

You will need to loop through all organisations to find the matching organisation.

**Third Problem**

I think this is a bad place to do this sort of manipulation. You should perhaps add an [after_create hook](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) to the user model and put these logic in that method.

Comment: Hi, that's all sensible advice. Thanks - I'll give it a try. Do you think my approach is still dangerous if I include the 'a' in my email_format attribute.

Comment: lol, good point there though. It might be sufficient with an "@"